# GAE/GWT: Error loading modules: Unable to find 'com/androidstartup/serialization/KPadProject.gwt.xml'

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, module, restlet, gae-module

I am using Eclipse 3.5 with GAE SDK 1.3.7 and GWT SDK 2.1.0 and Restlet 2.0.3. When I run my app, the console log shows:

```
Loading modules
   com.androidstartup.serialization.KPadProject
      [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/androidstartup/serialization/KPadProject.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
[ERROR] shell failed in doSlowStartup method
```

The main module `/KPadProject.gwt.xml` is in the root package. I checked out the configuration and I think it's all right.

At this point I don't know what to do to solve this problem.

Comment: I have the same problem after coping the project. Rebuilding does not work for me. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Did u find the solution @JoheGreen ?

Comment: @Damasia ? did u find the solution

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, one of these two solves the problem:

1. Project -> Properties -> Java build path:

   - Is your XML included in the source?
   - Is the order okay?
2. In the project you are loading, include the KPadproject as follows:

   ```
   <inherits name='com.androidstartyp.serialization.KpadProject'/>;
   ```

   That is the entire path, with dots instead of slashes, and without the `.gwt.xml` extension.