# Gwt: unable to find MyModule.gwt.xml

Tags: gwt, eclipse-plugin

May be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127101/gae-gwt-error-loading-modules-unable-to-find-com-androidstartup-serialization), but I have not found an appropriate solution. I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Unable to find 'main/java/com/blabla/MyModule.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
```

How do I fix it?

`com.blabla package` is under `src/main/java` source folder

PS. I'm using eclipse plugin

**edit:**
Possibly it will help, here is a record from .classpath file:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be caused by one of the two mistakes:

- In some module, you actually wrote  Just start a search over all
  the files, should be easy to be found, change it to the
- You are running compiler/DevMode and forcing it compile module
  main.java.com.blabla.MyModule Just check eclipse launch
  configuration/ant script (whatever you use) and found
  Compiler/DevMode launch arguments. Just find
  main.java.com.blabla.MyModule and change it to the
  com.blabla.MyModule

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be your classpath starts from just **src** directory. Not from **src/main/java**. main/java also considered as a java source packages.You can change this in java build path. In that change the source folders starting with **src** to **src/main/java** .

Hope this solves the problem. I am sorry if this is not related to your issue.

Comment: My classpath is started from src/main/java